# Integrating exterior forms?

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, determinant, exterior-algebra, jacobian

Let's say I like to normalise the components of a wedge product in the following way, say for two one-forms (forming a bivector):

$\omega \wedge \zeta = W_{[i} Z_{j]} dx^i \wedge dx^j = 1!1!/(1+1)! (W_iZ_j - Z_iW_j) dx^i \wedge dx^j$

Where [ ] denotes anti-symmetrisation brackets.

When I want to do an integral using exterior forms, however, let's say:

$\int f(x,y) dx \wedge  dy = \int f(x(x'),y(y')) dx' \wedge dy' = \int F$

Won't my measure, embedded in the forms, become distorted by the 1/2! normalisation I put in the components of my wedge product?

I imagined something might go wrong since this factor does not feature in the determinant I would normally use, were I doing a change of variables in 'ordinary' integration.

Comment: Perhaps ∫ f(x(x′),y(y′)) dx′ ∧ dy′ actually picks up a factor of (1/2!)^-1 = 2 when I do the wedge product this way?

Comment: This is a perennial battle with the definition of the wedge product. Most of us put a compensating factor so that the volume of the unit cube in $\Bbb R^n$ will be $1$ and not $1/n!$, but some authors choose to "simplify" things by having one less factor and the wrong value of volume.